# PlasticSCM revision tree for multiple files

Tags: plasticscm

In the PlasticSCM client GUI, is there a way to view a "joint" 2D revision tree for more than one file? That is, to see all changesets which touched one of a set of files I specify.

I can't find a way to view anything else than "revision tree of one file" or "revision tree (actually, branch explorer) of entire repo."

Basically, is there a Plastic equivalent to the following git command?

```
gitk -- include/a.h src/a.cpp docs/call_sequence.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plastic SCM allows you to get the revision tree for only one file at a time.

Comment: Not really the answer I wanted to hear, but thanks anyway :-) Time to file a feature request...